# acces/pass object from outside of class to class method

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, dropzone

I have created a class for getUserMedia. All is working fine as long as i want to add recorded blob into a Dropzone.

I have initialized Dropzone object like:

```
var threadUpload = $("#thread-upload form").dropzone({...});
```

Initialized object UserMediaRecorder like:

```
var recorder = new UserMediaRecorder({
    openbutton: '#video-tab',
    containerClass: 'noSwipe noSwipe2',
    constraints: {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            width: { max: 1920 },
            height: { max: 1920 },
            facingMode:"user",
            frameRate: {ideal: 30, min:10},
            aspectRatio : 1920/1080
        }
    },
    limit: 10,
    onfileupload: function(blob, threadUpload){
        console.log(blob);
        threadUpload.addFile(blob);
    }
});
```

Whole class `UserMediaRecorder` can be seen heree: https://jsfiddle.net/igor77/zkqg27eh/31/

My problem is that I am unable to pass blob to Dropzone object `threadUpload`. I tried to pass it as parameter but doesnt change anything, it still comes up as undefined. Is there any way how to pass blob into Dropzone from inside other class?

Answer (score 0):

You are losing your current scope when binding the click event listener on your `sendButton`.

To solve this make the function from your evenListener a method in your class and then pass it to your eventListener binding you class scope.

ex:

```
this.sendButton.addEventListener('click', this.sendVideo.bind(this));
```

and then in your class you add the `sendVideo` method:

```
sendVideo() {
   var blob;
   if (this.sendButton.textContent === 'Send Picture') {
            blob = this.dataURItoBlob(this.canvas.toDataURL( 'image/jpeg' ))
            this.clearCanvas();
            console.log('sending pic');
        }else if(this.sendButton.textContent === 'Send Video'){
            blob = new Blob(this.recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/mp4'});
            console.log('sending vid');
        }
    this.onfileupload(blob);
    this.sendButton.disabled = true;
}
```

here's the full code. Please note that it won't run due to security limitations but pasting it back in your fiddle would work.

```js
class UserMediaRecorder {
    constructor(options) {
        this.openbutton = '#openRecordPanel';
        if (typeof options.openbutton !== 'undefined'){
            this.openbutton = options.openbutton;
        }
        this.lengthSeconds = false;
        if (typeof options.limit !== 'undefined'){
            this.lengthSeconds = options.limit;
        }
        this.msecondsLeft;
        this.isPaused = false;
        this.constraints = {audio: true, video: true};
        if (typeof options.constraints !== 'undefined'){
            this.constraints = options.constraints;
        }
        this.containerClass = '';
        if (typeof options.containerClass !== 'undefined'){
            this.containerClass = options.containerClass;
        }
        if (typeof options.onfileupload !== 'undefined'){
            this.onfileupload = options.onfileupload.bind(this);
        }
        
        this.openVideoPanelButton = document.querySelector(this.openbutton);
        this.openVideoPanelButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.openVideoPanel();
        });
        
        console.log('initialized');
    }
    async bindElements(){
        this.closeVideoPanelButton = this.overlay.querySelector('button.close-record-panel');
        this.video = this.overlay.querySelector('video');
        this.canvas = window.canvas = this.overlay.querySelector('canvas');
        this.switchCameraButton = this.overlay.querySelector('button.switch-camera');
        this.stopButton = this.overlay.querySelector('button.stop-recording');
        this.recordButton = this.overlay.querySelector('button.start-recording');
        this.snapshotButton = this.overlay.querySelector('button.snapshot');
        this.sendButton = this.overlay.querySelector('button.send-recording');
        this.counterBlock = this.overlay.querySelector('div.counter');
        console.log('elements defined');
    }
    async bindEvents(){
        this.closeVideoPanelButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.closeVideoPanel();
        });
        this.switchCameraButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
            this.switchCamera();
        });
        this.stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.stopRecording();
        });
        this.recordButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            if (this.recordButton.textContent === 'Start') {
                this.canvas.style.display = "none";
                this.startRecording();
            }else if(this.recordButton.textContent === 'Pause'){
                this.pauseRecording();
            }else if(this.recordButton.textContent === 'Resume'){
                this.resumeRecording();
            }
        });
        this.snapshotButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (this.snapshotButton.textContent === 'Snapshot') {
                this.canvas.style.display = "block";
                this.canvas.width = this.video.videoWidth;
                this.canvas.height = this.video.videoHeight;
                this.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
                this.snapshotButton.textContent = 'Cancel';
                this.sendButton.disabled = false;
                this.sendButton.textContent = 'Send Picture';
            }else if(this.snapshotButton.textContent === 'Cancel'){
                this.clearCanvas();
            }
        });
        this.sendButton.addEventListener('click', this.sendVideo.bind(this));
        window.addEventListener('onfileupload', this.onfileupload.bind(this));
        console.log('events bound');
    }
    sendVideo() {
        var blob;
        if (this.sendButton.textContent === 'Send Picture') {
            blob = this.dataURItoBlob(this.canvas.toDataURL( 'image/jpeg' ))
            this.clearCanvas();
            console.log('sending pic');
        }else if(this.sendButton.textContent === 'Send Video'){
            blob = new Blob(this.recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/mp4'});
            console.log('sending vid');
        }
        this.onfileupload(blob);
        this.sendButton.disabled = true;
    }
    async openVideoPanel(){
        this.overlay = document.createElement('div');
        this.overlay.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);z-index:1100;';
        document.body.appendChild(this.overlay);
        
        this.overlay.innerHTML = '<div class="' + this.containerClass + '" style="width:100%;height:100%;display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:center;justify-content:center;">' +
        '<div style="position:relative">' +
        '<video autoplay playsinline muted style="max-width:100vw;max-height:100vh"></video>' +
        '<canvas style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;max-width:100vw;max-height:100vh;display:none"></canvas>' +
        '<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;top:auto;bottom:20px;display:flex;flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content:center;">' +
        '<div style="width:auto"><button class="switch-camera">Switch Camera</button></div>' +
        '<div style="width:auto"><button class="stop-recording" disabled>Stop</button></div>' +
        '<div style="width:auto"><button class="start-recording">Start</button></div>' +
        '<div style="width:auto"><button class="snapshot">Snapshot</button></div>' +
        '<div style="width:auto"><button class="send-recording" disabled>Send</button></div>' +
        '<div class="counter" style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">00:00:00</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<button class="close-record-panel" style="position:absolute;top:20px;left:auto;right:20px;">Close</button>' +
        '</div>';
        await this.bindElements();
        await this.bindEvents();
        await this.initStream();
        console.log('opened');
    }
    closeVideoPanel() {
        if (this.stream) {
            this.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                track.stop();
            });
        }
        this.overlay.remove();
    }
    async initStream() {
        try {
            this.stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.constraints);
            this.handleSuccess(this.stream);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('navigator.getUserMedia error:', e);
        }
    }
    handleSuccess() {
        window.stream = this.stream;
        this.video.srcObject = this.stream;
    }
    async switchCamera() {
        console.log('getUserMedia() switching camera:', this.stream);
        if(this.constraints.video.facingMode === "user"){
            this.constraints.video.facingMode = "environment";
        }else{
            this.constraints.video.facingMode = "user";
        }
        console.log('Camera changed to ' + this.constraints.video.facingMode);
        await this.initStream(this.constraints);
    }
    startRecording() {
        this.snapshotButton.disabled = true;
        this.sendButton.disabled = true;
        this.stopButton.disabled = false;
        this.recordButton.textContent = 'Pause';
        
        this.recordedBlobs = [];
        let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'};
        if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
            console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
            options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'};
            if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
                console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
                options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
                if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
                    console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
                    options = {mimeType: ''};
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e);
            return;
        }
        
        console.log('Created MediaRecorder', this.mediaRecorder, 'with options', options);
        this.mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
            console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
        };
        console.log(this);
        this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
            if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
                this.recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
            }
        };
        this.mediaRecorder.start(10); // collect 10ms of data
        console.log('MediaRecorder started', this.mediaRecorder);
        this.startTimer();
        return this.recordedBlobs;
    }
    stopRecording() {
        this.mediaRecorder.stop();
        this.stopTimer();
        this.recordButton.textContent = 'Start';
        this.snapshotButton.disabled = false;
        this.sendButton.disabled = false;
        this.sendButton.textContent = 'Send Video';
        this.stopButton.disabled = true;
        console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', this.recordedBlobs);
    }
    pauseRecording(){
        this.mediaRecorder.pause();
        this.pauseTimer();
        this.recordButton.textContent = 'Resume';
    }
    resumeRecording(){
        this.mediaRecorder.resume();
        this.resumeTimer();
        this.recordButton.textContent = 'Pause';
    }
    clearCanvas(){
        this.snapshotButton.textContent = 'Snapshot';
        this.canvas.style.display = 'none';
        this.canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        this.sendButton.disabled = true;
    }
    dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
        var byteString, 
        mimestring 
        if(dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') !== -1 ) {
            byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1])
        } else {
            byteString = decodeURI(dataURI.split(',')[1])
        }
        mimestring = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
        var content = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            content[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)
        }
        return new Blob([new Uint8Array(content)], {type: mimestring});
    }
    startTimer(){
        if (!this.isPaused && this.lengthSeconds){
            this.msecondsLeft = this.lengthSeconds * 100;
        }else if(!this.lengthSeconds){
            this.msecondsLeft = 1;
        }
        var that = this;
        var counter = function(){
            if (that.msecondsLeft > 0){
                if(!that.lengthSeconds){
                    that.msecondsLeft++;
                }else{
                    that.msecondsLeft--;
                }
                var ms = that.msecondsLeft % 100;
                if(ms < 10){ ms = "0" + ms}
                var s = ((that.msecondsLeft - ms) / 100) % 60;
                if(s < 10){ s = "0" + s}
                var m = ((that.msecondsLeft - ms - (s * 100)) / 100) /60;
                if(m < 10){ m = "0" + m}
                that.counterBlock.innerHTML = m + ":" + s + ":" + ms;
            }else{
                that.stopRecording();
                that.isPaused = false;
            }
        };
        this.timer = setInterval(counter,10);
    }
    resumeTimer(){
        this.isPaused = true;
        this.startTimer();
    }
    pauseTimer(){
        this.isPaused = true;
        this.stopTimer();
    }
    stopTimer(){
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
}

var recorder = new UserMediaRecorder({
    openbutton: '#openRecordPanel',
    containerClass: 'noSwipe noSwipe2',
    constraints: {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            width: { max: 1920 },
            height: { max: 1920 },
            facingMode:"user",
            frameRate: {ideal: 30, min:10},
            aspectRatio : 1920/1080
        }
    },
    limit: 10,
    onfileupload: function(blob){
        console.log(blob);
        //  threadUpload.addFile(blob);
    }
});
```

Comment: still getting console.log(threadUpload); as undefined when call it inside function at onfileupload:

Comment: is it passed as a parameter to the function on function call?

Comment: yes i am passing it in function like onfileupload: function(blob, threadUpload){...} whilie initializing UserMediaRecorder

Comment: oh, sorry, you don't have to pass it as a parameter, just use it inside the function

Comment: since you are not calling your function with that parameter from within your class it will always be undefined. so remove it from the parameter list.

Comment: great now it have the object but when i try to use threadUpload.addFile(blob); I am getting error Uncaught TypeError: threadUpload.addFile is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189303/discussion-between-iacobalin-and-igor-mizak).